# Discord bot pings and then is stuck

Tags: python, discord, bots, minecraft

I saw from someone this code and I wanted to try it out only it doesn't work so well anymore when my minecraft server goes offline it changes the channel but when the minecraft server goes back online it doesn't change and stays stuck. Can someone help me solve this problem? The bot is in Python.

Greetings ItsJeBoyGoogle

P.S. Sorry for my bad english ._.

```
import discord
import asyncio
import time
import socket
TOKEN = "token"

client = discord.Client()

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Connected")
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(id)            
    def ping(ip, port):
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((ip, int(port)))
            return True
        except:
            return False
    while True:
        online = ping("26.51.174.109", "25565")
        if online == True:
            print("server online")
            await channel.edit(name = "Server Status - Online")
        else:
            print("server offline")
            await channel.edit(name = "Server Status - Offline")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
client.run( TOKEN )
```

Comment: do you get any error message when you run code in console/terminal?  It is always good idea to `close()` files and sockets. System may block socket/port for some time if you don't close it.

Comment: first you should run code without `try/except` to see if you get error - now you may have error which makes all problem but you don't know it because `except` hides it. Or you should at least display some message - `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: some servers may block socket and  it is good to set timeout - ie, `s.settimeout(5)` - before connection.

Comment: Could you rewrite it for me. I'm new to python and don't know how everything works. Because i'm poor and can't pay a course :( 

Greetings ItsJeBoyGoogle

Comment: there is nothing to rewrite - use `s.settimeout(5)` before `s.connect(...)` - that's all.

Comment: still don't work and it don't change to "offline"

Answer (score 0):

Some servers may block socket so it is good to set timeout. It can be good also to close socket.

Often it is good to display exception to see what can be the problem.

```
def ping(ip, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket() # standard values are `socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM` so you don't have to write them
        s.settimeout(5)
        s.connect((ip, int(port)))
        s.close()
        return True
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[Exception]', ex)
        return False
```

---

Code which I used for tests

```
import discord
import asyncio
import time
import socket
import os

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

def ping(ip, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket() # standard values are `socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM` so you don't have to write them
        s.settimeout(2)
        s.connect((ip, int(port)))
        s.close()
        return True
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[Exception]', ex)
        return False

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Connected")
    
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    #channel = client.get_channel(id)            
    
    while True:
        online = ping("26.51.174.109", "25565")
        #online = ping("192.168.1.101", "8081")
        if online:
            print("server online")
            #await channel.edit(name="Server Status - Online")
        else:
            print("server offline")
            #await channel.edit(name="Server Status - Offline")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        
client.run(TOKEN)
```

---

**EDIT:**

I tested port with [nmap](https://nmap.org/) - `nmap -Pn 26.51.174.109 -p 25565` and it shows that port is filtered so I think you could assume that it is `online` when it gives `timeout` because it doesn't refuse connection.

```
def ping(ip, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket() # TCP - standard values are `socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM` so you don't have to write them
        s.settimeout(2)
        print('[DEBUG] connect')
        s.connect((ip, int(port)))
        #result = s.connect_ex((ip, int(port)))
        #print('result:', result)
        return True
    except socket.timeout as ex:
        print('[DEBUG] timeout')
        return True        
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[Exception]', ex)
        return False
    finally:
        print('[DEBUG] close')
        s.close()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You have to create value

```
id = ...channel number...
```

because there is built-in function `id()` and it may use this function as channel number.

Check

```
print(id, type(id))
```

and you should see

```
<built-in function id> <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Comment: so I changed the code with the code that you provided me but it sill don't work and I don't know how but it gave me can't connect to host because the server is offline

Comment: what doesn't work? Do you see new line `server ....` in console/terminal every 5 seconds? Maybe server is `Offline` all time so you can't get it as `Online`. Or maybe it use different port. Your IP:PORT gives me `offline` all time. But if I test with my server WWW then it shows me `online`

Comment: or maybe server has some secure system to block this kind of connection.

Comment: or maybe you should assume that if it gives `timeout` exception then it is `online` because it didn't refuse connection.

Comment: I tested port with [nmap](https://nmap.org/) - `nmap -Pn 26.51.174.109 -p 25565` and it shows that port is active but it filters connections so you could assume that when it gives timeout then it is online

Comment: okay I got something to work if I don't use the channel name changer the pinger works fine and update but not when I add that it need to ping the channel it gets stuck and then crash

Comment: your problem can be that you use `id` which you didn't create `id = ...` but there is built-in function `id()` and it tried to use this function so it can makes problem. Use `print(id)` and `print(type(id))` and you should see `<built-in function id> <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`

Comment: Okay what I got to work is that if the server is already started and I then start the bot it will work and change when I close the server it will go to offline and when I start the server it says server online but not change and no more server online after 10 and 20 sec I have it like id = XXXX and channel = client.get_channel(id)

Comment: I added all your code and it now only says its online and not anymore with offline and if the server is offline it says its online and doesn't change

Comment: I don't have your server, and I can't test i. I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

I got this atm

```
import asyncio
import time
import socket
import os

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

id = 848949245557473350
client = discord.Client()

def ping(ip, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket() # TCP - standard values are `socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM` so you don't have to write them
        s.settimeout(2)
        print('[DEBUG] connect')
        s.connect((ip, int(port)))
        #result = s.connect_ex((ip, int(port)))
        #print('result:', result)
        return True
    except socket.timeout as ex:
        print('[DEBUG] timeout')
        return True        
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[Exception]', ex)
        return False
    finally:
        print('[DEBUG] close')
        s.close()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Connected")
    
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(id)
    print(id, type(id))
    
    while True:
        online = ping("frfr1.quackhost.uk", "20960")
        #online = ping("192.168.1.101", "8081")
        if online:
            print("server online")
            await channel.edit(name = "Server Status - ")
        else:
            print("server offline")
            await channel.edit(name = "Server Status - ")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        
client.run("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```